# Undocumented CoreAudio control classes

Tags: macos, core-audio, hal, fourcc

While exploring the CoreAudio HAL object tree, I came across two mysterious boolean controls that are exposed on the built-in microphone and the built-in output on my MBP with macOS 10.13 but don't appear anywhere in the documentation or system framework headers.

On the built-in mic, the control's class FourCharCode is `'donz'`, it's a subclass of `'togl'` (kAudioBooleanControlClassID), it's set to `true` and is read-write.

On the built-in output, the control's class FourCharCode is `'evis'`, this one too is a descendant of `'togl'`, it's set to `false` and is read-write.

I'm curious if anybody else has bumped into these or know anything about their purpose.

Comment: How did you explore the HAL object tree?

Comment: @RuurdAdema I recursively walked the objects returned for the `kAudioObjectPropertyOwnedObjects` property of `kAudioObjectSystemObject`